# Static property of another project in solution is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 projects in the same solution. Project1 which is an web app and Project2 being an Web api core. I'm trying to read the web.config of Project1 from Project2. To do this, on application start I set the property TestProp of class TestClass at startup in Global.asax.

```
namespace Project1
{
    public class TestClass
    {

        public static String TestProp { get; set; }
    }


namespace Project1
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestClass.TestProp = (string)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["somekey"];
        }
}
```

Then in Project2 controller, I call the property but it's always returning null.

```
string x = Project1.TestClass.TestProp;
```

I added the property to watch and it's assigned correctly at startup of Project1, but the moment I call the property from Project2, it changes to null in the watch. I searched for answers and all I read says it should be quite straight forward. I'm looking at it for hours and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `System.Web.HttpApplication` is not ASP.NET Core. Please use correct tags in future.

Comment: _"I'm trying to read the web.config of Project1 from Project2"_ - You can't do that: `web.config` files are not supported in ASP.NET Core because the old XML-based `System.Configuration` library was removed.

Comment: Your `TestProp` property is only set when `Application_Start` is invoked - so ask yourself how/when/where `Project1.Global.Application_Start` will be invoked (hint: it won't). ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core are very, very different beasts: the only thing they have in common is having a similar name.

Comment: I understand that .Net core does not use web.config files. That is the reason I want to read it from Project1, which does support it. I used the Core tag because Project2 is .Net Core. As to Application_Start, I do run both projects. As I mentioned, the property TestProp does get set at startup, as I can see in the watch (and also set breakpoints to make sure it gets there). The moment I try to read it, I see it change back to null in the watch. This is the part I can't figure out.

Comment: Project1 and Project2 run in separate processes and don't share in-memory data - use the **Debug Location** toolbar and you'll see that.

Comment: If you have referenced the project1 .dll from project2, you'll need to add the setting key/value to project 2 .config file too.